# Could we restore some animal's muscle structure by it's bone?

Tags: zoology, bone-biology

Suppose that elephant dies out one day, nothing left to researchers but the fossil. Could fossil infer the existence of large nose?

If there is possibility, how exactly should they perform the deduction?

Comment: I think you would be surprised to know that forensic experts use the skull and face bone structure of a dead body to predict how the person might have looked, probably by getting the muscle structure from bone structure. I don't know whether it's true, I heard it in a TV show.